# How to center content of GridLayoutManager?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

Just trying to center my RecyclerView horizontal.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here the java code:

```
mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
itemLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 6);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(itemLayoutManager);
...
mItemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, mItemList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mItemAdapter);
```

When I run the application the recyclerview aligns left.
What exactly do I have to do to center the content so that the margin is the same left and right like in the example picture on the right side?

[image]

Comment: Make sure your item width is `match_partent` ,and add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your `RecyclerView`

Comment: Setting width of the item to match_parent worked, thanks :)
Weird because in my old projects it worked exactly like I did it but now I have to change something.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like to set paddings to item:

```
class SpacingItemDecorator (private val padding: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration()
{
    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    )
    {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        outRect.top = padding
        outRect.bottom = padding
        outRect.left = padding
        outRect.right = padding
    }
}
```

Now in Your RecyclerView set `paddingStart` and `paddingEnd`, e.g `4dp` :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:spanCount="6"/>
```

When You create adapter just apply this item decorator:

```
val x = (resources.displayMetrics.density * 4).toInt() //converting dp to pixels
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(SpacingItemDecorator(x)) //setting space between items in RecyclerView
```

RecyclerView item:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{Integer.toString(dataView.id)}"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently and looked into the source code. There's no straight forward way to do this using GridLayoutManager. The other was is to use a GridView which is more customisable.

This is an alternate solution for you or any one else looking for a workaround.

I didn't want to change to a GridView so this is what I did. I set the RecyclerView's layout width to wrap_content and centered it horizontally within the parent (which in your case is a RelativeLayout so it will be something like `android:centerHorizontally="true"`)

I knew the item width so I calculated the spanCount by dividing the screen width by the item width (plus any horizontal margins). Now I set the span count to the grid layout manager and it gets centered horizontally just how you want it.

Adding margins to you item's layout root play an important role here.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter GridLayoutManger for recyclerview doesn't center vertically

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"         
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Just set the recyclerview to width to `wrap_content` then add  `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:gravity="center"`

**Additional Info**
Your layout file for the recyclerview parent should be  `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`